# my flutter app doesnt work currectly in release mode

Tags: flutter, sms, release, signing

I finished my project after apply every test on app in many device, but when i signed it and try to upload on store, it require release mode, i did it but after that my app has an error on this line belong to sending sms process, i've studied all of the same problem but they didn't solved my problem.

in gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

also i add all of the access permission to manifest,
below line doesn't work properly (it not send any sms)

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
 make_sign();
 }

//making signature for aouto_sms_field plugin
void make_sign()async{
  final signature= await SmsAutoFill().getAppSignature;
  _app_signature= signature ?? "";
  print(_app_signature);
  _listenOTp();
   snd_sms(_login._phone, _app_signature);
 }

//function to API for sending sms
 void snd_sms(String phone, String signature)async {
 print('now_sms_from_server');

///now sending sms function to server
  var body= Map<String,dynamic>();
  body["phone"]=_login._phone;
  body["signature"]=_app_signature;
  Response response1 = await http.post(Uri.parse('https://www.myapi.com/home/send_sms'),
    body: body,);
    _sms_val= (json.decode(utf8.decode(response1.bodyBytes))).toString(); <====== ///error appear in this line

}

//waiting for sms and aouto_field values in textfield
  void _listenOTp() async{
  await SmsAutoFill().listenForCode;
   }
```

all of the system worked very well before, but now this line has error.

```
I/flutter (24004): now_sms_from_server
E/flutter (24004): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)]
Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at 
character   1) 
E/flutter (24004): <!DOCTYPE html>
E/flutter (24004): ^
E/flutter (24004): 
E/flutter (24004): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-
patch/convert_patch.dart:1404)
E/flutter (24004): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber 
(dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1271)
E/flutter (24004): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-
patch/convert_patch.dart:936)
E/flutter (24004): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert-
patch/convert_patch.dart:40)
E/flutter (24004): #4      JsonDecoder.convert 
(dart:convert/json.dart:506)
E/flutter (24004): #5      JsonCodec.decode 
(dart:convert/json.dart:157)
E/flutter (24004): #6      _authenticationState.snd_sms 
(package:mana_app/login_form.dart:586)
E/flutter (24004): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24004):
```

Comment: Can you share the error console code

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1),  E/flutter (24004): <!DOCTYPE html>
E/flutter (24004): ^
E/flutter (24004): 
E/flutter (24004): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404)
E/flutter (24004): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1271)